# How can i unsubscribe all subscriptions in my app?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a big app where I have a lot of subscribe methods. If I want to unsubscribe from one of them, then I will use this code:

```
getUsersSubscription: Subscription;

ngOnInit() : void {

   this.getUsersSubscription = this.userService().subscribe(users => {
     ...something
   })
}

ngOnDestroy() : void {
   this.getUsersSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

The problem is that I have a lot of pages - components too. I have jwt token, and when it expires, I am logging the user out. The problem is when I am doing that, some calls are still happening... How can I unsubscribe from all things in my app after log out so I don't need to repeat this step for all my subscriptions through all components in my page?

Also I am using interceptr to catch that jwt expiration and I am redirecting the user to the login page.But there are calls that are still made in the login page, if the user clicks something - seconds before he is logged out

Comment: you should use intercepter and check the status code. if you got 401 then redirect on the login screen.

Comment: I am using that.When i redirect to login page then some calls are still maked because not all subscriptions are unsubscribed

Answer (score 1):

If you need to unsubscribe to a lot of `Observable`, you should use a `Subscription` array:

```js
private subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
    this.subscriptions.push(this.userService.subscribe(users => {
     ...something
   }));
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscriptions.forEach(subscription => subscription.unsubscribe());
}
```

But I think that your real problem is that you may have way to much subscription than you need to.

First, you should use the `async` pipe when possible. It handle the subscription and unsubscription very well and at no cost.

Also, be aware that you generally do not need to unsubscribe from cold observables (like the ones returned by `HttpClient`) because when an http request is done, the observable is terminated.
You only have to unsubscribe to cold observables that have side effects.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.How i will put my this.getUsersSubscription in that array when he should be initialised with subscription on the right ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to initialize the array. I updated the example

Comment: The array is initialized before the code enters `ngOnInit`. `this.userService.subscribe(...)` returns a `Subscription` object that will be pushed in the array.

Comment: Btw, you **do need** to unsubscribe cold observables in an Angular app, because if there's a pending http request, and you change the page to another route, the request will not be cancelled unless you unsubscribe it's observable on component's `onDestroy` method.

Comment: @AliDemirci Thanks for your comment. If you cancel the subscription to a cold observable, the http request will not be cancelled but at least your app will ignore the result.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the previous to options you might as well go the following route:

You can use the `takeUntil()` [operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takeuntil), which automatically unsubcribes for you once a given event takes place.
For example:

In some component

```
...

myObservable$ = this.service.foo().pipe(
  takeUntil(this.loginService._loggedOutEmitter) <-- (0)
).subscribe()

...
```

In loginService

```
...

_loggedOutEmitter = new Subject<boolean>(); <---- (1)

loggedOut() {
  *some logout logic *
  this._loggedOutEmitter.next(true); <----------- (2)
}

...
```

Just like in the other solutions you would have to import a specific service and would have a specific line you would need to add per Observable (0), but this way should be slightly friendlier in terms of memory since you would not need to track your subscriptions.
Instead you only have one more Observable (1) which emits once (2).

Still I feel like the way you proposed it (Clearing in OnDestroy [which by the way could and in my opinion should also be done with the takeUntil() method]) is cleaner.